# PDF format. function of %-started sequence

Tags: pdf, file-format

What is a function of hex sequence "25 E2 E3 CF D3", found at the beginning of some documents? It should be a comment as far as I understand, but it's content is not any meaningful text and the same sequence occurs in many documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It identifies the PDF file as containing binary data.

From the [freely available PDF Reference](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) (section 7.5.2, p. 40):

> If a PDF file contains binary data, as most do (see 7.2, "Lexical Conventions"), the header line shall be
>   immediately followed by a comment line containing at least four binary characters—that is, characters whose
>   codes are 128 or greater. This ensures proper behaviour of file transfer applications that inspect data near the
>   beginning of a file to determine whether to treat the file’s contents as text or as binary.